# Why does winapi insist on using PCSTR instead of PCWSTR when used for window class from within class constructor?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, compiler-errors

I am programming a simple UI using WINAPI. I have a problem with compilation insisting on using the A version of the functions despite my UNICODE definition. I have two version of a code one working but not ideal for what I wished, and other packed into the constructor of a class. The code provided has compiler error and does not build.

Sorry if the question is long and full of code,didn't know how to explain it without examples but I hope too much is better than too little.

Compiling on default Visual Studio 2017 compiler.

MainWindow class is inheriting from BaseWindow template class.
The working version with default constructor being as follow:

```
MainWindow mainWindow;
if (!mainWindow.Create(L"Awesome Erpidzi", WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, g_WindowWidth, g_WindowHeight))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    ShowWindow(mainWindow.Window(), ncmdShow);
```

and Create function from parent class:

```
BOOL Create(
        PCWSTR lpWindowName,
        DWORD dwStyle,
        DWORD dwExStyle = 0,
        int x = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int y = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int nWidth = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int nHeight = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND hWndParent = 0,
        HMENU hMenu = 0
    )
    {
        WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };

        wc.lpfnWndProc = DERIVED_WINDOW_TYPE::WindowProc;
        wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        wc.lpszClassName = ClassName();

        RegisterClass(&wc);

        m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            dwExStyle, ClassName(), lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,
            nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this
        );

        return (m_hwnd ? TRUE : FALSE);
    }
```

and ClassName function being simple:

```
PCWSTR  MainWindow::ClassName() const
{
    return L"MainWindow";
}
```

Yet when I pack the function inside the constructor of MainWindow class like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(PCWSTR windowName, DWORD style, int width, int height)
{
    Create(windowName, style, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height);
}
```

I recieve a compilation error

> CreateWindowExA(DWORD,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,DWORD,int,int,int,int,HWND,HMENU,HINSTANCE,LPVOID)':
> cannot convert argument 2 from 'PCWSTR' to 'LPCSTR'

From debugging I found out the Create function at `wc.lpszClassName` expects LPCSTR type.
And my question is why when I put the function in the constructor it suddenly wants ASCII type string and not UNICODE ? And how can I fix it to work with wide character strings ?

Here is the full cpp files code of main, basewindow and mainwindow.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif // !UNICODE

#include <Windows.h> 
#include "IncludeAll.h"

const int g_WindowWidth = 1024;
const int g_WindowHeight = 768;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR args, int ncmdShow)
{


    MainWindow mainWindow;
    if (!mainWindow.Create(L"Awesome Erpidzi", WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, g_WindowWidth, g_WindowHeight))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    ShowWindow(mainWindow.Window(), ncmdShow);

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

#ifndef WIN_UI_BASE_INCLUDE
#define WIN_UI_BASE_INCLUDE

#include <Windows.h>

template <class DERIVED_WINDOW_TYPE>
class BaseWindow
{
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        DERIVED_WINDOW_TYPE *pThis = NULL;

        if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
        {
            CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
            pThis = (DERIVED_WINDOW_TYPE*)pCreate->lpCreateParams;
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pThis);

            pThis->m_hwnd = hwnd;
        }
        else
        {
            pThis = (DERIVED_WINDOW_TYPE*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        }
        if (pThis)
        {
            return pThis->HandleMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        else
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    BaseWindow() : m_hwnd(NULL) { }

    BOOL Create(
        PCWSTR lpWindowName,
        DWORD dwStyle,
        DWORD dwExStyle = 0,
        int x = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int y = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int nWidth = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int nHeight = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND hWndParent = 0,
        HMENU hMenu = 0
    )
    {
        WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };

        wc.lpfnWndProc = DERIVED_WINDOW_TYPE::WindowProc;
        wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        wc.lpszClassName = ClassName();

        RegisterClass(&wc);

        m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            dwExStyle, ClassName(), lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,
            nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this
        );

        return (m_hwnd ? TRUE : FALSE);
    }

    HWND Window() const { return m_hwnd; }


protected:

    virtual PCWSTR  ClassName() const = 0;
    virtual LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = 0;

    HWND m_hwnd;
};
#endif 
#ifndef WIN_UI_MAINWINDOW_INCLUDE
#define WIN_UI_MAINWINDOW_INCLUDE

#include "WIN_UI_Base.h"

class MainWindow : public BaseWindow<MainWindow>
{
public:
    MainWindow();
    MainWindow(PCWSTR windowName,DWORD style, int width, int height);
    PCWSTR  ClassName() const;
    LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

};

#endif
#include "../IncludeAll.h"

LRESULT MainWindow::HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
        ColourPicker& rColourPicker = UIHelpers::GetColourPicker();
        const HBRUSH brush = rColourPicker.GetBrushWithColour(eColour::eWhite);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, brush);
        EndPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;

    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(m_hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(PCWSTR windowName, DWORD style, int width, int height)
{
    Create(windowName, style, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height);
}

PCWSTR  MainWindow::ClassName() const
{
    return L"MainWindow";
}
```

Comment: `CreateWindowExA` means unicode is not being used. You seem to only define UNICODE in one of your files.

Comment: Adding the UNICODE definition to all the files actually resolved the issue. The problem was with the order compiler read the files from includes.

Comment: Normally you can set this in your project settings. I mean define the UNICODE preprocessor symbol in Visual Studio.

Comment: This is very useful to know, if you post this as an answer I could mark it as accepted.

Comment: Better yet, don't rely on the preprocessor at all. Since you've used `PCWSTR` (instead of `PCTSTR`) you should go Unicode all the way. That means, use `WNDCLASSW` in place of `WNDCLASS`, `RegisterClassW` in place of `RegisterClass`, etc. [Conventions for Function Prototypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes) explains the (up to) three variants available for all Windows API calls. The TL;DR-version is: Append a `W` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the main problem is you defined `UNICODE` in only one of your source files instead of all of them. One way to avoid this problem in Visual Studio is to define `UNICODE` as a preprocessor definition in your project settings.

The setting is
`Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions`

Make sure to add this setting for all configurations instead of only the current.